# Parar la música cuando sales de la aplicacion Android Studio

Tags: java, android

estoy implementando en mi aplicacion una radio, funciona todo bien pero el problema es que si le doy al boton de atras sigue sonando la musica de radio, en el activity layour anterior y si me salgo de aplicacion sigue sonando. Os paso por aqui mi codigo.

```
public class Radio extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private String url_radio= "http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio2_mf_p";
private ProgressBar playSeekBar;

private Button buttonPlay;

private Button buttonStopPlay;

private MediaPlayer player;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio);

    initializeUIElements();
    initializeMediaPlayer();

}

//Inicializamos los elementos
private void initializeUIElements() {

    playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    playSeekBar.setMax(100);
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    playSeekBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

    buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
    buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);


}


private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        player.setDataSource(url_radio);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            playSeekBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(100);
            Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
        }
    });
}

private void startPlaying() {
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

    //Cada vez que pulse el boton start salga el SeekBar
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    player.prepareAsync();

    player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            player.start();


        }
    });

}


private void stopPlaying() {
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        initializeMediaPlayer();
    }

    buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
    playSeekBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    //Si pulso al boton stop me quita el SeekBar
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



}


//Cada vez que pulse el boton de start empiece la musica y cuando pulse el boton de Stop pare la musica
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonPlay) {
        startPlaying();
    } else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {
        stopPlaying();
    }

}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        //  player.stop();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Usa el método `onDestroy()` de tu Activity para determinar se esta cerrando la aplicación y detienes el `MediaPlayer`:

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

      if (player != null && player.isPlaying()) {
           player.stop();
           player.release();   
      }


    }
```

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -negativo, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicarlo.